# Bug with a delay of soaring in Safari. Which way to look to solve the problem?

Tags: css, animation, safari, hover, webkit

Redid some elements in the old project from angular.js to css. Hover delay is observed once. I tried it on different machines, different systems, different engines - the problem is obviously in Safari.

However, everything is written with prefixes and there are no intricate properties.

Here is the link: http://188.246.226.81:8888 The question is about hovers in the menu where "services" "cashback" "promotional codes" "goods on coupons"

By the way, "goods on coupons" works without delay and lags, this error is only on the main page. The question seems simple if the situation were not so strange.

Thanks in advance for helping everyone who responds.